# Как замутить человека используя библиотеку telebot?

Tags: python-3.x, telebot

мне нужно чтобы при входе в чат, человека мутило до тех пор, пока он не нажмёт на кнопку. Как это реализовать?

Пока есть вот такой код

```
#Создаем клавиатуру
markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
register = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Пройти регистрацию', url='ya.ru')
markup.add(register)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['new_chat_members'])
def greeting(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, text='Привет, ты попал в офицальную беседу .... Нажми на кнопку ниже чтобы продолжить.', reply_markup=markup)
```

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду под словом "мутить" в данном контексте?

Comment: @CrazyElf         mute наверное

Comment: @CrazyElf чтобы человек не мог писать, это позволяет телеграмм. Другими словами, Интик прав